# Specifying image in the css class

Tags: html, css, wordpress

So I've got this HTML:

```
<img class="avia_image " src="http://86.art-solveig.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/f-psychedelia-2.jpg" alt="" title="" itemprop="contentURL">
```

And I want to edit the CSS.

Editing it as so:

```
.avia_image:hover {

        content: url('http://86.art-solveig.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/f-psychedelia-1.jpg');
    }
```

(to change the image when hovering)

will produce this result all across each and every page using this class (avia_image).

I want to specify that it is only for THIS image: src="http://86.art-solveig.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/f-psychedelia-2.jpg"

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

```
.avia_image[src="http://86.art-solveig.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/f-psychedelia-2.jpg"]:hover {
     content: url('http://86.art-solveig.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/f-psychedelia-1.jpg');
}
```

That should work, though ideally you should just put a either an id on the img, or a different class to easier select it.

Comment: Accept his answer if it works. It's the least thing you can do besides saying Thank you.